# Remove item of List of parent class type through LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics

I have a List of Parent Class, containing items of objects made up of child class. For example

```
Class Vehicle
{
String Name;
}

Class Car: Vehicle
{
int Speed;
}

Class Bike: Vehicle
{
int Milage;
}

List<Vehicle> transports = new List<Vehicle>;
transports.Add(new Car{Name = "Fiat", Speed = 70});
transports.Add(new Bike{Name = "Bajaj", Milage = 70});
transports.Add(new Car{Name = "BMW", Speed = 100});
```

Now I want to delete the items of type car which have speed of 100. How can I do this. Preferable through linq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
transports.RemoveAll(x => x is Car && (x as Car).Speed == 100);
```

Comment: Bravo. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want:

```
var carsToRemove = transports.OfType<Car>().Where(c => c.Speed == 100).ToArray();

foreach (var car in carsToRemove)
{
    transports.Remove(car);
}
```

?

Comment: It is a bad idea in the general case to remove items from a C# List in a for loop, as this is O(N^2).

Comment: @svinja: in general, it's a bad idea to use `List<T>`, when you need fast items searching. Also, if you're looking for micro-optimizations, it's a bad idea to use `as` instead of casting, when the result is predictable (no `null` value can be returned).

Comment: O(N^2) vs O(N) is not a "micro" optimization.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code :**
you can remove item using [RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx)

```
transports.RemoveAll(c => c is Car && (c as Car).Speed == 100);
```

i hope it will help you.